# Can´t check if array values are true from another class in main class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, if-statement, boolean

I am programming a basic writing game in C#. The game will randomly show picture in a picturebox. The pictures is stored in an array in a different class than the main class.

The code to the class looks like this :

```cs
public class bildelisteDyr
{

    public static Bitmap bildeListe (int index)
    {
        Bitmap[] bildeListe = new Bitmap[21];

        bildeListe[0] = Properties.Resources.ål;
        bildeListe[1] = Properties.Resources.ant;
        bildeListe[2] = Properties.Resources.bird; 
        bildeListe[3] = Properties.Resources.bear;
        bildeListe[4] = Properties.Resources.butterfly;
        bildeListe[5] = Properties.Resources.cat;
        bildeListe[6] = Properties.Resources.chicken;
        bildeListe[7] = Properties.Resources.dog;
        bildeListe[8] = Properties.Resources.elephant;
        bildeListe[9] = Properties.Resources.fish;
        bildeListe[10] = Properties.Resources.goat;
        bildeListe[11] = Properties.Resources.horse;
        bildeListe[12] = Properties.Resources.ladybug;
        bildeListe[13] = Properties.Resources.lion;
        bildeListe[14] = Properties.Resources.moose;
        bildeListe[15] = Properties.Resources.polarbear;
        bildeListe[16] = Properties.Resources.reke;
        bildeListe[17] = Properties.Resources.sheep;
        bildeListe[18] = Properties.Resources.snake;
        bildeListe[19] = Properties.Resources.spider;
        bildeListe[20] = Properties.Resources.turtle;
        return bildeListe[index];
    }    
}
```

When calling on the values in the array to show picture randomly in the picturebox it all works well. This is done like this :

```cs
pictureBox1.Image = bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(r.Next(0, 20));
```

But I have three times where I need the code to check the value of the picturebox to do a something. I have one play sound button, one button that give a label a text and one button to check given answer from a textbox. None of them seems to work. Here are some code :

Give text to label :

```cs
 if (pictureBox1.Image == bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(0))
 {
     svarPåOppgave.Text = "ÅL";
 }
 else if (pictureBox1.Image == bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(1))
 {
     svarPåOppgave.Text = "MAUR";
 }
 // etc.
```

Play sound button :

```cs
if (pictureBox1.Image == bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(0))
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
    player = new SoundPlayer("lyd/dyr/ål.wav");
    player.PlaySync();
}
else if (pictureBox1.Image == bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(1))
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
    player = new SoundPlayer("lyd/dyr/enmaur.wav");
    player.PlaySync();
}

// etc.
```

Checking if correct answer is given :

```cs
if (pictureBox1.Image == bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(0))
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "ål")
    {
        riktigLyd.Play();

        poengInt += 1;

        textBox1.Text = "";

        pictureBox1.Image = bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(tilfeldigBildet);

        tekstTilLabel();

        svarPåOppgave.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {

        feilLyd.Play();

        poengInt -= 1;

        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    String poengString = poengInt.ToString();
    label1.Text = poengString;
    textBox1.Select();

}
else if (pictureBox1.Image == bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(1))
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "maur")
    {
        riktigLyd.Play();

        poengInt += 1;

        textBox1.Text = "";

        pictureBox1.Image = bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(tilfeldigBildet);

        tekstTilLabel();

        svarPåOppgave.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {

        feilLyd.Play();

        poengInt -= 1;

        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    String poengString = poengInt.ToString();
    label1.Text = poengString;

} // etc.
```

I would guess there was something wrong with the if statements like

```cs
if (textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "ål")
```

But I can´t seem to understand what?

To sum it up, when I debug the program I get the random picture from the other class. But when I press the buttons on the program nothing happens. No sound, no text to label and no checking of answer.

Comment: You could simply store the index number of the selected image in the Tag() property of the PictureBox and then check that instead of checking the Image() property...

Comment: Use debugger: set breakpoint, analyze values, path of execution(step through your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some unusual architectural choices here, but the specific problem you're facing is that you're re-creating the `Bitmap`s every time, and comparisons are performed by reference, not by value.

Change your `bildelisteDyr` class as follows:

```
public class bildelisteDyr
{
    static Bitmap[] bildeListeInternal;

    static bildelisteDyr() {
        bildeListeInternal = new Bitmap[21];
        bildeListeInternal[0] = Properties.Resources.ål;
        //...
        bildeListeInternal[20] = Properties.Resources.turtle;
    }

    public static Bitmap bildeListe (int index) {
        return bildeListeInternal[index];
    }
}
```

Some more resources on the conceptual problem:

- [== Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)
- [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your good respons. But now I get : Error 2 Ambiguity between 'AngelinaSkriver2.bildelisteDyr.bildeListe' and 'AngelinaSkriver2.bildelisteDyr.bildeListe(int)' \\psf\Home\Desktop\Ang\AngelinaSkriver2\AngelinaSkriver2\bildelisteDyr.cs 22 9 AngelinaSkriver2

Comment: That's caused by the fact that the internal member and the function have the same name. I've edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Two errors left : public bildeListeDyr() gives Error 1 Method must have a return type \\psf\Home\Desktop\Ang\AngelinaSkriver2\AngelinaSkriver2\bildelisteDyr.cs 20 16 AngelinaSkriver2

Comment: and return bildeListeInternal[index] gives : Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AngelinaSkriver2.bildelisteDyr.bildeListeInternal' \\psf\Home\Desktop\Ang\AngelinaSkriver2\AngelinaSkriver2\bildelisteDyr.cs 49 16 AngelinaSkriver2

Comment: I've probably fixed both of those with my last edit. Before posting any more errors, it would be great if you could try and figure out what's causing them.

Comment: Public void solved the first problem, but the other problem is just solved if I make in non-static. Is that okey?

Comment: I just did. :) But can I have it non-static?

Comment: I put it to non-static but I can´t seem to call it my main class now. I use :         bildelisteDyr bildeListe = new bildelisteDyr();
        bildeListe.bildeArray(); -- I changed the methods name to bildeArray().

Comment: The code that I've given you there should work statically. If you want to make it non-static, you have to make the constructor, `bildeListInternal` and `bildeList` all non-static, and then put an instance of the class somewhere where it can be accessed by all functions in your main class, for example, in the class definition as a class member.